# Reading enviromental variable problem in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my excel.js:

```
    let test = async () => {
         console.log(process.env.DATABASE_HOST);
         .......
    }
    test();
```

Here is my package.json fragment:

```
"scripts": {
    .............
    "excel": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./server/excel.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  }
```

My .env.development is stored in the application root folder.
Here is my .env.development:

```
DATABASE_HOST=dbServer
```

When I execute the following command line in the application root folder:

```
npm run excel
```

It should return "dbServer", unfortunately, it returns undefined.
How can I fix it?

Comment: did you add `dotenv` package and enabled it `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: Yes,I forgot to do so. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `dotenv` package, and require it `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: I have installed the dotenv package, I just forgot to add the `require('dotenv').config()` statement at the beginning of my code.